# How to format double to raw number, not format in number scientist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

My problem is value of variable "**interest**" is showned in format number scientist have E. for example: i want value when return is **23874928374923749823749823749** but actually is **387492837492375E28**

How do i resolve it?
Thanks so much!

Controller:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/i/v1/calculate")
public class CalculateController {    
@RequestMapping(value = "/calculate", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public ResponseEntity<List<RespDto>> calculate() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.calculate());
    }
}
```

File response dto: RespDto

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class RespDto implements Serializable {
    private Double interest;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use double for this if you want the precision all the way down to 28 digits. A double only has limited precision. The format itself is just a matter of printing (research  number formatting), but you may get something like 387492837492375000000000000000.

Comment: You should use BigDecimal instead, but then no operators but functions. Look into the javadoc and remember `toPlainString`. I assume you are aware that floating point is just an approximation, a sum of (negative) powers of 2.

Comment: @JoopEggen: I change to use BigDecimal, however in response return it still have E

Comment: `interest.toPlainString()` would not use the scientific notation with `E`.

Comment: @JoopEggen but the type of data of "interest" I return in response DTO is Double and currently, I don't want to change the type to String so I think I can't use interest.toPlainString()

Comment: Then first check that 23874928374923749823749823749 can be held in a double, is not equal to the value 1 lower.  The double has a resolution of 1 at that magnitude. I doubt that a bit. **But** simply formatting to a non-E string can be done with ``%f".formatted(x)` But also `...5E28` already hints at an imprecision.

Comment: @JoopEggen: thanks so much, I create class extends JsonSerializer to over function serialize, use "interest.toPlainString()" resolved my problem.